# How to view my posts and responses on official Apple Support Community website?

Tags: apple-id

I have an account with [Official Apple Support Community](https://discussions.apple.com/) linked to my AppleID. The username on the site is different from the Apple ID. I want to find a question that I asked on the website, but there is no way to see posts or comments I have made that is assigned to my username.

I've tried searching my username in the search bar as well, and that is not working either. I'm able to look up posts involving other users (if the post text contains the username) but nothing comes up when I look for text containing my username.

**How do I search my posts and responses on the site?**

---

**EDIT:** When signed in, I've tried going to the "My Subscriptions" page but nothing shows up. I even played around with all the filters, and checked the "Authored" and "Participated" filters but I get no posts.
[image: Official Apple Support Community My Subscriptions tab showing no posts when using the filter titled "Authored"]
[image: Official Apple Support Community My Subscriptions tab showing no posts when using the filter titled "Participated"]
I noticed it says ***"There is  no recent content available"***. Could this be because the posts were made years ago, and haven't been indexed? One post was made in 2013 while another was in 2016, and I know this because I was able to find two posts by googling `site:https://discussions.apple.com "MY_USERNAME"`.

Comment: On the very page you linked in your question there is a section named "See your content at a glance with My Subscriptions" where there is a link [Manage your content](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209032) which tells you how to see your content at a glance!

Comment: When I go to the "My Subscriptions" page, nothing shows up. I even tried playing with all the filters and turning off the filters. Nothing under my username shows up in that section. Even after trying the "Authored" and "Participated" filters, no subscriptions or posts show up. However, I know I've made posts. I could find some of them by googling `site:https://discussions.apple.com "USERNAME"`.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this same question in the appropriate Apple forum and see if it does show up in Subscriptions.  This would be the normal place:  https://discussions.apple.com/community/using_apple_support_communities

Answer (score 1):

After you sign in, the main Welcome screen displays. Here's a screenshot of the top right portion of that sreen:

[image: screenshot]

At the top right, select "My subscriptions." That should return a list of the threads to which you're subscribed, and I think one is automatically subscribed to threads one starts.

I don't know if subscriptions (or their listings) are automatically cancelled after a period of time.

Comment: When I go to the "My Subscriptions" page, nothing shows up. I even tried playing with all the filters and turning off the filters. Nothing under my username shows up in that section. Even after trying the "Authored" and "Participated" filters, no subscriptions or posts show up. However, I know I've made posts. I could find some of them by googling `site:https://discussions.apple.com "USERNAME"`. How recent was this feature added? Because some of the posts I made were many years ago. Could they perhaps be too old to have been indexed?

Comment: @Wimateeka I don't know. Perhaps that's the answer. The Welcome screen I'm referring to looks different from the one you mention. I'll add a screenshot to my answer.